# Nth Tetrehedral number mod m?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Hi i'm stuck on my assignment which partly requires me to find the nth tetrahedral number mod m. Tetrahedral numbers are the sum of the all the n previous triangle numbers and are denoted by the formula (n(n+1)(n+2))/6. Given that i am supposed to find the modulo of the number and that the nth triangular number can exceed the size of a long long int, may i know is there a method to calculate this or another way to find the nth tetrahedral number? The modulo m can reach up to 100000 so i'm not sure if pascal's triangle will work here. Thank you.

Comment: Good luck with that....seriously: give it a try and then post what you wrote so far...

Answer (score 1):

[Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) has the property that

```
(a*b) % m == ((a % m) * (b % m)) % m
```

You can use that equivalence to keep your numbers in a range of standard integer types. You should take care when you divide the sum by 6, though, because the modulo equivalence isn't necessarily true for division. You can circumvent this by calculating everything modulo `6*m` first and then take everything modulo `m`.

Your calculations must be able to multiply two numbers modulo `m` safely. Here, you need at most (6 · 100,000)², which fits into a 64-bit integer, but not in a 32-bit integer:

```
std::uint64_t tetra_mod(std::uint64_t n, std::uint64_t m)
{
    std::uint64_t m6 = 6*m;

    std::uint64_t n0 = n % m6;
    std::uint64_t n1 = (n + 1) % m6;
    std::uint64_t n2 = (n + 2) % m6;

    return (n0 + n1 + n2) % m6 / 6 % m;
}
```